# MSSQLSERVER being shutdown by NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've ran into a problem in a windows 7 running Microsoft SQL Server. The SQL service randomly shuts down. When I check the logs, the only messages from the crashing time are these 3 lines (always the same, except for the date and time):

> 2017-09-12 19:52:28.23 spid13s     Service Broker manager has shut
>   down. 2017-09-12 19:52:28.90 spid51      Server shut down by request
>   from login NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. 2017-09-12 19:52:28.90 spid51      SQL
>   Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an
>   informational message only; no user action is required.

I've checked the event viewer and there's no relevant message around that time, except for the Aplication log, showing the same messages around the same time, and the System log, showing

> SQL Server service (MSSQLSERVER) changed state to "stopped"

(I've translated the message from spanish to english, so it might be a little different in english, but thats about it)

How can I check whats stoping the service? I've verified all scheduled tasks and there's nothing around that hour.

Thanks!

Comment: can you also check the error logs

Comment: >>> spid51...by request from login...<<< it was a user session logged to server, it was not just a service stop requested by smth out of server. To prevent this from happening you can drop NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM from sysadmin role. As it will miss SHUTDOWN permission, it just will not be able to do it anymore. Why is NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM the member of sysadmin role? Is it SQL Server service account?

Comment: The account needs to run with sysadmin privileges. Also, I dont understand when you say that this was a user session logged in. How can someone login with the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link.Hope It will work.

[SQL Server services keep on Stopping](http://answerhub.flowsoftware.com/questions/583/why-does-sql-server-services-keep-on-stopping.html)

Follow these steps also :

You can check the security log of the server and see who/what logs in and out around that time. You also have to check System Center Operations Manager 2012 and see if it is doing or trying to do around that time. Also check any local or remote jobs/services that is running some scripts and this is a collateral damage. Please check who all has system admin access and try to cut them to bare minimum. Disabling one sysadmin account at a time and see if that stops it from happening can help identifying who/what is doing this. If your server is on a virtual environment check the virtual host logs as well, may be that can bear some pointers.